# Windows tweaks, mostly for explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

I've got a few Tweaks on my Vista machine that I wanna get up and running on Windows7 as well, but I forgot which program(s) can enable them.

For instance, when I right click on a map, I see the option "open command window here".
Also, the "Move To" and "Copy To" options are really useful, yet it's been so gosh darn long I just don't remember which programs are reliable to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XdN Tweaker](http://xenomorph.net/?page_id=336) may offer some of what you are looking for, and it has updated to support Win7

Answer (score 4):

Holding Shift shows the "Open Command Window Here" when right clicking.

Here is something for those other context menu items.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-copy-to-move-to-on-windows-vista-right-click-menu/